# Is there a way to detect the ios < > form navigation buttons using jquery and trigger actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form that when the next and previous (< >) form navigation buttons are pressed, they are detected and can trigger various actions, for example trigger a bootstrap modal and focus on the first input element, or open a collapsible element without the virtual keyboard closing so that the form navigation seems to flow naturally.

Is there any way to detect this? I've been searching for a couple of hours with no luck whatsoever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use focus or blur event listeners (or both actually).

```
$('.your-input').bind("focus blur",function(event){

         event.type; // This will either be focus or 
                     // blur depending on wether you just came 
                     // or left from this input

         // do stuff

});
```

Comment: File, de boreis na fantasteis pos m'eswses! :) THANKS!